What is Decoherence?
What precisely is decoherence? Assume familiarity with the density matrix formalism of quantum mechanics.
I read this related question, but I am looking for a more precise answer than the one given. I would also like to avoid mention of "decoherence is ... evolution of a density matrix into diagonal form" as Zurek himself states this to be an imprecise characterization of the theory$^1$.


W. H. Zurek, "Quantum Theory of the Classical: Einselection, Envariance, Quantum Darwinism and Extantons", 2022, https://doi.org/10.3390/e24111520.


Possible duplicate: What is quantum decoherence?

Related: Quantum Decoherence, What is 'coherence' of a quantum system (with examples)?, Are electrons in a p n junction delocalized across the junction?

Heuristically, decoherence describes a mechanism by which a system immersed in an environment irreversibly evolves into a classical probability mixture of pointer states characterized by their resistance to entangling with the environment. A pointer states is a quantum analog of a "classical state" in the sense that pointer states do not change under ambient interaction with the environment (a state of a classical chair is thought to be invariant under interactions with its ambient environment). I attempt a more precise treatment below. First, introducing concepts native to quantum mechanics. Then, introducing concepts from decoherence.
Quantum Mechanics
Consider an open quantum system $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_S \otimes \mathcal{H}_E$ with Hamiltonian $H: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$. Suppose that $\mathcal{H}$ initially occupies a pure product state $\rho_0 = \lvert \psi_{0,s} \rangle \langle \psi_{0,s} \lvert \otimes \lvert \psi_{0,e} \rangle \langle \psi_{0,e} \lvert$. Finally, suppose for simplicity that $H$ is independent of explicit time dependence, so the time evolution operator is $e^{-itH}$.
In general, the time evolved state
$$\rho(t) = e^{-itH} \lvert \psi_{0,s} \rangle \langle \psi_{0,s} \lvert \otimes \lvert \psi_{0,e} \rangle \langle \psi_{0,e} \lvert e^{itH}$$
will be an entangled state. Moreover, physically we often do not have access to information stored in the environment. Hence, what is accessible to us is the reduced density matrix of the system
$$\rho_S(t) = \text{Tr}_E(\rho(t)). \tag{1}$$
Let $\{\lvert s_i\rangle \}$ and $\{\lvert e_j \rangle\}$ constitute a Schmidt basis of $\mathcal{H}$. Then, we concretely write $(1)$ as
$$\rho_S(t) = \sum_{i,j,k}a_ia_j\biggl(\mathbb{I} \otimes \langle e_k \lvert\biggr) \biggl(e^{-itH} \lvert s_i \rangle \langle s_j \lvert \otimes \lvert e_i \rangle \langle e_j \lvert e^{itH}\biggr) \biggl(\mathbb{I} \otimes \lvert e_k \rangle\biggr). \tag{2}$$
Decoherence
Now, suppose there exists a Schmidt basis of $\mathcal{H}$, given by  $\{\lvert p^s_i \rangle \}$ and $\{\lvert p^e_j \rangle \}$ such that
$$1-\text{Tr}(\text{Tr}_E(e^{-itH} \lvert p^s_i\rangle \langle p^s_i \lvert \otimes \lvert p^e_j \rangle \langle p^e_j \lvert e^{itH})^2) = 0 \quad \text{for all time} . \tag{3}$$
The system part of this Schmidt basis $\{\lvert p^s_i \rangle \}$ is called a pointer basis. Condition $(3)$ says that each element of this pointer basis does not entangle with the environment for all time. Writing $(2)$ in this pointer basis,
$$\rho_S(t) = \sum_{i,j,k}c_{i}c^*_{j}\biggl(\mathbb{I} \otimes \langle e_k \lvert\biggr) \biggl(e^{-itH} \lvert p^s_i\rangle \langle p^s_j \lvert \otimes \lvert p^e_i \rangle \langle p^e_j \lvert e^{itH} \biggr) \biggl(\mathbb{I} \otimes \lvert e_k \rangle\biggr).$$
Time evolution can be absorbed into the basis itself and we obtain
$$\rho_S(t) = \sum_{i,j,k}c_{i}c^*_{j}\biggl(\lvert p^s_i(t)\rangle \langle p^s_j(t) \lvert \otimes \langle e_k \lvert p^e_i(t) \rangle \langle p^e_j(t) \lvert e_k \rangle\biggr). \tag{4}$$
Decoherence is said to occur when
$$\langle e_i \lvert p^e_j (t)\rangle \to \delta_{ij}.$$
In which case, $(4)$ becomes
$$\rho_S(t) = \sum_{i} \lvert c_{i}\lvert ^2 \lvert p^s_i(t)\rangle \langle p^s_i(t) \lvert ,$$
which can be interpreted as a statistical mixture of pointer states of the system $\{\lvert p_i^s \rangle\}$. Hence, the physics of decoherence is in studying the behavior of the transition $\langle e_i \lvert p^e_j (t)\rangle \to \delta_{ij}$.
This can be reasonably considered a quantum analog of a classical state because it is a (i) classical probability mixture of (ii) states left unchanged by interactions with the ambient environment. We remark that not every system admits a pointer basis and when it does exist, it is not necessarily unique.

This answer offers little in the way of conceptual understanding that the OP seems to be looking for.

@MattHanson The answerer is the OP.

@VincentThacker somehow I still agree with Matt Hanson - the answer certainly offers mathematical precision but all of the conceptual understanding of this pointer basis is hidden

@QuantumMechanic I am stating a fact and not a opinion. It is true regardless of what you think of the previous comment. As such I don't understand your objection.

@VincentThacker agreed, don't worry, not trying to say you are wrong in any way. The worry is that, since you directly responded to the previous commenter, someone may read your comment as answering/overriding the previous comment. I left a comment to note for future readers that Matt Hanson's comment is yet to be fully addressed.
To sum: yes, OP was looking for precision, so they have answered with mathematical precision. If someone wanted a more precise way of conceptually understanding decoherence, then they would need to add to this answer

When information is copied out of a quantum system interference between different values of the monitored observable is suppressed. A macroscopic object, that is anything you can see with the naked eye, is constantly having information copied out of it by the environment on a timescale much shorter than the timescales involved in its evolution, e.g. - photons reflecting from it, air molecules colliding with it etc. As a result of this process interference is suppressed for a set of observables called pointer observables monitored by the environment consistently over time for macroscopic objects: this process is called decoherence. This has the effect that the pointer observables can be used to store information reliably over time and these observables evolve according to classical equations of motion to a good approximation, see Section 3 of Decoherence and Ontology, or: How I Learned To Stop Worrying And Love FAPP and section 2 of Schlosshauer's review article on decoherence.
The reason why decoherence isn't just evolution of the density matrix into a diagonal form is that the density matrix is Hermitian so it's always diagonal in some basis. Decoherence makes the density matrix diagonal of a macroscopic object diagonal in the same basis over time and leads to the expectation values of pointer observables evolving over time in a good approximation to classical physics.
